# Развернуть массив задом наперед?

Tags: java, массивы

Почему массив до конца не разворачивается и дает такой результат `[5, 4, 3, 4, 5]`?

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int dlina = arr.length;
    System.out.println(dlina);

    for(int i = 0; i < dlina; i++) {    
        arr[i] = arr[dlina -= 1];    
    }            
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));    
}
```

Comment: Вам нужно просто вывести значения в обратном порядке? Или создать новый массив со значениями в обратном порядке?

Comment: создать новый массив со значениями в обратном порядке

Answer (score 3):

Вы затираете одни элементы другими из того же массива:

```java
public class Inverse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
      int dlina = arr.length;
      System.out.println(dlina);

      for(int i = 0; i < dlina/2; i++){
        int v = arr[i]; // Сохраняем "нос"
        int j = dlina - 1 - i; // Индекс для "хвоста"
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = v;
      }
  
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

С новым массивом еще проще:

```java
int[] inverseArray = new int[arr.length];
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    inverseArray[i] = arr[arr.length - 1 - i]; // в начало нового массива добавляем конец старого
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В первой(и последующих) итерациях цикла, заменяемое число просто затирается заменяющим, а должно попадать на его место. Т.е. когда пятерка из конца попадает в начало, то единица не попадает на место пятерки, а должна.

Answer (score 1):

Еще один небольшой пример в копилку

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    int left = 0, right = arr.length - 1;
    while (left < right) swap(arr, left++, right--);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}

public static void swap(int[] array, int i, int j) {
    int tmp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = tmp;
}
```

Вывод

```
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr={1,2,3,4,5};
        int dlina= arr.length;
                System.out.println(dlina);
        for(int i=0;i<dlina;i++){

        arr[i]=dlina-i;

        }
            

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));       
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте ваш код с таким массивом `{100, 101, 102, 103, 104}`

Comment: , но ваш ответ я полностью поддерживаю )

Comment: @fox это хорошо, а вот E_java вводите в заблуждение своим шуллерством :)

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class tes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr={100, 101, 102, 103, 104};
        int dlina= arr.length;
                System.out.println(dlina);
        for(int i=0;i<dlina;i++){

        arr[i]=dlina-i+99;

        }
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));       
    
    
    
}

}
```

нетничего невозможного))

Comment: Смешно, а для такого `{101, 195, 358, 9965654, 532, 654}`?

Comment: Надеюсь вы понимаете, что вы не массив разворачиваете (то есть его элементы), а что-то связанное с его индексами :)

Comment: конечно ) (длинна - переменная)